# Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Client HTTP compresssion

Tags: c#, wcf, sdk, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2013

I am writing an application that uses Microsoft Dynamics CRM SDK (v 6 / CRM 2013 SP1):

```
OrganizationServiceProxy proxy = new OrganizationServiceProxy(OrganizationUri, HomeRealmUri, Credentials, null);
proxy.Authenticate();
```

Is there a way to to force an instance of **OrganizationServiceProxy** to use HTTP compression when communicating with Dynamics CRM?

Answer (score 1):

Compression is enabled on the server via WCF compression, it isn't on the client. See the article below.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/crminthefield/archive/2014/09/02/enable-wcf-compression-to-improve-crm-2013-network-performance.aspx

Comment: This relates only to WCF **responses** - data sent by Dynamics CRM server to a WCF client. I want to know how to get the WCF client to compress its **requests**.